# Elastic collision of two bodies, one in contact with ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, collision

I came across the following problem.

> A hemisphere S and a particle P are of the same mass m. P is dropped from a height h. S is kept on a smooth horizontal surface. The particle P collides **elastically** with the hemisphere at the point shown in the figure. If theta = 45 degree and after collision the velocity of the particle becomes horizontal. Find the velocities of hemisphere S and particle P after collision.

[image: Text]

Now clearly conservation of momentum along the horizontal can be applied (as there is no external horizontal force) to obtain an equation for the velocities. The other equation to determine both velocities is to be found from the elastic collision condition. However, due to the normal force from the ground, neither the total momentum nor the total kinetic energy is conserved before and after the collision (when we take the ball and hemisphere as system).

> My question is, how do I use the elastic collision condition here?

The problem was solved by considering the coefficient of restitution $e$ i.e. the ratio of relative velocities of separation and approach. Elastic collision is defined as the case of $e=1$. This gave us another equation through which we could solve for both velocities. However, upon calculation it is observed that **the total kinetic energy was not conserved.** Elastic collisions, by definition, conserve the total kinetic energy. How is this collision elastic then?  
Is $e=1$ an extended definition of elastic collision, when a third body is involved and the conservation of total kinetic energy doesn't hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Analysis

This is a three-body problem:

- hemisphere S, mass m
- particle P, mass m
- floor, mass unknown, but can be assumed close to infinity

For a collision involving three bodies, the two conservation laws (momentum and energy) do not provide a single solution. [This is already true for two bodies, that's why we need to know the geometry of the impact - the inclination of the surfaces where they touch, giving the force direction.]

For three-body collisions we typically separate the collisions, we assume that (in our case) first the particle and the hemisphere interact, and then separately the hemisphere and the floor - this assumption does not always fit, but let's apply it here.

The problem defines the first impact to be elastic. Because of the impact geometry, this exerts a 45-degrees left-downward force on the hemisphere, making it move in that direction. Up to now, energy has been conserved.

Now we have the second "impact" of the hemisphere with the floor. The problem description only tells us that the surface is smooth, probably meaning frictionless. But it doesn't answer the question whether impacts between a hemisphere and the floor are elastic or not.

Maybe, the problem has a non-elastic behaviour in mind (but didn't tell us). Then the impact reduces the vertical velocity component of the hemisphere to zero (assuming that the floor has a mass much greater than the hemisphere), and leaves only the horizontal component unchanged. And this non-elastic collision consumes the missing energy.

But if we assume the second impact to be elastic, then the impact inverts the vertical velocity component of the hemisphere, so it moves in left-upward direction after that - under the additional influence of gravity meaning that it starts bouncing. And in this case, the kinetic energy has been conserved.

### Problem criticism

The problem in not only ambiguous (in not defining the properties of the hemisphere-floor interaction), but also wrong in its assumptions.

If the particle and the hemisphere collide at the 45-degrees point, the particle will not leave in horizontal direction. With a 45-degrees inclined interaction force, the only solution resulting in a horizontal velocity will have the particle leave with the same speed it had before the impact. So all the kinetic energy will stay in the particle, and there's nothing left for the hemisphere, which is obviously impossible.